# React animation: Resize container, AND THEN add add contents

Tags: reactjs, css-animations

I need to create a React component that displays multiple rows (For this thread, let's just say each row correspond to a string. In reality, I need to create another component per row).

I want the following behavior every time the contents change:

1. Whatever current rows are displayed are removed with a fade of 1 second.
2. The component calculates the height needed for the new content (rowCount x fixed height) and animates to that height, also with a duration of 1 second.
3. The new rows are fade into view. Also with an animation of 1 second.

I've tried multiple strategies, but I can't get the animations to work one after the other.

Am I missing a simple solution? Is there a component out there that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your row has static size, then you can use [`animation-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) property in css.

If your animations are triggered by upper row components' animation end event, you can add `onAnimationEnd` listener to your components. you can call [`Element.animate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) function inside the listener.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationend_event
- https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#animationevent-handler

Comment: Thank you, that gives me a good starting point :)